# creating transaction with dynamic arguments (objects/variables)

Tags: javascript, abi, raw-transaction

My scenario is to make transactions (deploy contract, calling its functions, etc.) with arguments (which are dynamically created/extracted from some json abi file). For example;

```
function extractConstructorWithArguments()
{
        if (item.type === "constructor")
                constrObject.push(item.inputs)

 }
```

above function making constObject as follows;

[ [ { internalType: 'address payable',
      name: '_wallet',
      type: 'address' } ] ]

/////////// extracting parameters types and giving them valid dummy values

```
for(c=0; c<constrObject.length; c++){ // number of constructor
    for(d=0; d<(constrObject[c]).length; d++) // number of parameters
    {
            temp = constrObject[c][d].type
            switch(temp) {
                case 'string':
                    constrObject[c][d] = "ABC"
                  break;
                case 'uint8':
                    constrObject[c][d] = 126
                  break;

                case 'uint256':
                    constrObject[c][d] = 34535354
                    break;
                case 'address':
                    constrObject[c][d] = '0x2cAe18ac37d85CccdE2ebB63D0c391Fe1ac7c36f'
                    break;
              }
    }
}
```

above code produce this output

[ [ '0x2cAe18ac37d85CccdE2ebB63D0c391Fe1ac7c36f' ] ]

///////////////////// deploying contract now ///////

```
async function deployCon(key) {

  var paramLen= (constrObject[key]).length;
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(sources[key].abi);
if(paramLen == 0) {
  params = {
    data: '0x' + sources[key].bytecode,
};
}
else {
  params = {
    data: '0x' + sources[key].bytecode,
    arguments: constrObject[key] // HERE I Need Your suggestion 
};
}
const transaction = contract.deploy(params); 
const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey1);
receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
}
```

When i deploy above contract , there is following error;

```
    (node:12556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid type (arg="type", value="0x2cAe18ac37d85CccdE2ebB63D0c391Fe1ac7c36f")
    at Object.throwError (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\errors.js:68:17)
    at getParamCoder (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\abi-coder.js:862:12)
    at AbiCoder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\abi-coder.js:895:25)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AbiCoder.encode (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\ethers\utils\abi-coder.js:884:15)
    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\src\index.js:96:27)
    at C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:432:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object._encodeMethodABI (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:431:12)
    at deployCon (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy1.js:178:23)
    at main (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy1.js:142:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy1.js:150:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
(node:12556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:12556) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am confused why my changed variable is not working. ConstrObject is an array, may be this causing error.

**Smart Contract Source Code**:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.12;

contract MyContract {

    uint256 public  totalSupply ; 
    mapping( address => uint256) public  balances ;
    address payable public owner;

    constructor(address payable _wallet) public payable {
        totalSupply = 6;
        owner = _wallet;
    }

    function () external payable{
        buyToken();
    }

    function buyToken() public payable {
        require(totalSupply >= (msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2);
        balances[msg.sender] += (msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2;
        // wallet.tranfer(msg.value);
        totalSupply -=(msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2;

    }
    function getTotalSupply()public view returns  (uint256 ){
        return totalSupply;
    }
       function setTotalSupply(uint256 newSupply) public payable {
        // require(msg.sender == owner && totalSupply<1);
        totalSupply = newSupply;

    }

}
```

**JSON file**:

```
"abi": [
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "address payable",
          "name": "_wallet",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "payable": true,
      "stateMutability": "payable",
      "type": "constructor"
    },
```

**UPDATED:** Source code of contract and JSON portion of constructor

Comment: Good: `arguments: [arg1, arg2, arg3]`.

Comment: Bad: `arguments: [[arg1, arg2, arg3]]`.

Comment: Please tell us what is the value of `constrObject[key]`.

Comment: the value of constrObject[key] = [ 'ABC', 'ABC', 126, 34535354 ]

Comment: if i give  arguments: ['a', 'b', 12, 34] , still same error ... i have exhausted why previsouly set value ' constrObject[c][d] = "ABC" '   not changing .... ??????

Comment: What is your constructor prototype?

Comment: this is my first contract ... copy from ether scan https://etherscan.io/address/0xcb17cd357c7acd594717d899ecb9df540f633f27#code

Comment: another one is my own .. its constructor is as belows;
    constructor(address payable _wallet) public payable {
        totalSupply = 6;
        owner = _wallet;
    }

Comment: see my updated question with images

Comment: So how may I copy/paste text from that in order to put it into an answer?

Comment: now you can see all code , json and error... please guide me , i am really exhausted @goodvibration

Comment: `the value of constrObject[key] = [ 'ABC', 'ABC', 126, 34535354 ]` - why is it so, when your constructor takes a single argument???

Comment: see my updated question ... btw. i have solved it by putting my changed constObject into new array... thanks for your efforts..